Stable Diffusion ControlNet v1.1 causes me a problem urllib3 SSL
with all models, the error is:
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)>
It appears on the terminal after activating any Controlnet model and launching the render. The models are appropriately downloaded and placed in the right controlnet folder.
Around I found pages and pages on this topic but the solutions with only an installation exist only for MAC:

Just browse to Applications/Python 3.6 and double-click Install Certificates.command

but not for Windows.
I installed python version 3.10.6 which is the required one. How can this problem be solved?
I tried reinstalling everything several times. I tried changing python version but SD asks for that very version. I deleted the venv folder after updating the certificates with the command
pip install certifi --upagrade

No luck.
I tried canceling SSL verification from the internet options, but that didn't work either. The error keeps showing up the same.
I canceled the check by entering an environment variable set to zero. Unfortunately, I don't remember the name of that variable, but even if I did: it didn't work.

I have the same symptoms.
I think it's related to the company's security system, but I don't know what the problem is

I find it amazing that on linux I have no problem while on windows which is a paid system, I can't get it to work. And I am so happy to use windows licensed but only on vm. Otherwise do you know how many kicks I had to give?
